# How to specify time range in {aggregate}_over_time?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a Grafana chart that makes use of the sum_over_time(data_source[$__range]) and count_over_time(data_source[$__range]) command in Prometheus. Normally, it is working fine.

But, the commands don't run correctly when I set time range to a moment in the past, for example from now-3h to now-2h. For that example, the $__range in the command become 1h and the commands roll for data from 1 hour ago to now, which is not what I intended.

Is there any way to archieve that time range in Prometheus? Please help!

Comment: [`$__interval`](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/add-template-variables/#__interval) shouldn't be `1h`, unless you changed Max data points
to 1. Most likely you should use `$__range` instead.

Comment: Query is automatically evaluated for correct time of the dashboard. No  need for manual adjustments.